# Zend Framework: disable autoloading of base model tables

Tags: php, zend-framework

I use Module Autoloader to autoload resources (forms, Doctrine models etc.).
I do not use Zend_Db_Table at all.

When I load any Doctrine model,
e.g. `MyModule_Model_Test`, 
it tries to load `MyModule_Model_TestTable` too, so I get errors that the `MyModule_Model_TestTable.php` is missing.

To fix this, I may create empty class `MyModule_Model_TestTable` class and
everything works as expected.
*But I don't need this file.*

Strange that, when I move `MyModule_Model_TestTable` to `/anyDirDeeper/MyModule_Model_TestTable` without changing its name or content, the class is correctly loaded too…

How to configure Module Autoloader so it would not require this *…Table* classes?

I have in my application.ini:

```
resources.frontController.moduleDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules"
resources.modules[] =
```

And Module Bootstrap:

```
class MyModule_Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Module_Bootstrap {}
```

My app structure is similar to this:

```
/application/
    /modules/
        /mymodule/
            /models/
                /Db/
                   *Mymodule_Model_Db_Test*
            *Mymodule_Model_Test*
```

Comment: I know that there is no good way to load  Doctrine Models  with Modules but 
after reading about your tries to load Doctrine Models you inspired me to move the Doctrine Bootstrap code to the module  , to be honest i don't how to answer your question :( and i haven't test it yet but it sounds interesting

Comment: It works when I autoload models in bootstrap, but does not in controller actions…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this issue was produced because I used the same module name and resource type name (registered by default).

Models were named: `Acl_Model_Modelname` and `Acl_` namespace was registered with autoloader. Changed model namespace to something else and it works.